# How to import a .py file to Qubole?

Tags: qubole

I'm connecting to Azure data lake, and I have the file there, but it's in a different path, and I don't know how to import it. 
Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below steps -->

->  sc.addPyFile("cloudstoragepath")
-> Then run the  import `filename_without_py_extension` after that

I hope this is your requirement as per what I understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for running a python script by importing it from azure blob or data lake, file path can be passed in 'query path' selection in Qubole Analyze. Please check below screenshot for sample.

[image: azure qubole spark run]

If this is not what you are looking for do let us know the exact requirement and we would be happy to help !!

Comment: Thank you, I did that. But how do I call it now in the Jupyter Notebook? I have functions in it that I want to use in the PySpark notebook I'm running.